# How can I send a large amount of text from a webview to objc?

Tags: javascript, objective-c, ios, webview

I'm trying to build an "iBooks-like" reader for iPhone. I'm receiving a huge amount of text (html) from my webservice, columnizing it (inside a webview, via javascript) and then trying to send an array of "columns" back to objective c from javascript (from the webview) in order to create the viewControllers I need to use UIPageViewController (one per column, or basically one per page).

I'm using shouldStartLoadWithRequest to intercept every location change in the webview, taking the url as method to call and the first string after a "/" as parameter for that method in this way:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webViewRef shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{

    //NSLog(@"REQUEST: %@", request);
    NSURL *URL = [request URL]; //Get the URL

    if ( [[URL scheme] isEqualToString:@"objc"] ) {

        NSMutableString *host = [[URL host] mutableCopy];

        [host appendString:@":"];

        SEL method =  NSSelectorFromString( host );

        NSArray *chunks = [URL pathComponents];

        NSString *stringToPass = [[chunks objectAtIndex:1] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        NSLog(stringToPass);

        if ([self respondsToSelector:method])
        {
            [self performSelector:method withObject:stringToPass afterDelay:0.1f];
        }

        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

My main problem right now is that, probably, the text is too long for the url to actually contain it (in fact if I NSLog it, it gets cut). Is there a better method to achieve the same thing?

Should I create a local server or open a socket to send data from JS to objc or there is an easier way at the moment?

Comment: How about pagination sort of thing from your web service end, every request receive text for first 5 pages only then when user flips 3 page call for another 5 and cache it chunk by chunk.

Comment: I can't paginate from the webservice, unluckily (I don't have control over it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could ask to the webview the code you need by calling a JS function like that:

NSString* htmlData  = [_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"jsFunction()"];

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of work, but you could define a chunking protocol to use for sending the data back in the location changes. This way each "column" could be broken up into a discrete and digestible number of pieces, and assembled on the iOS side.

For example:

```
http://bridge.myapp.com/?segnum=2&segtotal=5
```